# Vaild objects showing status as 'invalid' in user_objects.,

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration

While executing the query below, I'm getting the list of object with status as 'INVALID'.,

```
SELECT * FROM USER_OBJECTS WHERE STATUS='INVALID';
```

When I checked the status of the objects individually, they are in compiled state.,

**Even after dropping those objects**, they're still showing up when I execute the same query.,

Any clue, why it is behaving soo?

Comment: Are you connected the the same schema executing these 2 actions?

Comment: Yes, dcieslak., And the objects are Packages.,

Comment: the only thing that I can imagine is that somebody modify SYS.USER_OBJECTS view. Check it.

Comment: Is it possible to update an oracle table.,? Cud U help me in checking the same, pls?

Comment: Change your query to `SELECT * FROM SYS.USER_OBJECTS WHERE status='INVALID';`

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason is that somebody created in your schema USER_OBJECTS table. And this table was populated by data from USER_OBJECTS view.

```
select * from user_tables where table_name = 'USER_OBJECTS'
```

Execute the above query. In case it returns rows it means you found your issue.
Just drop the USER_OBJECTS table and you will start to get results from USER_OBJECTS view.

Comment: It doesn't return any row, for table_name='USER_OBJECTS' :(

Comment: while executing ALL_OBJECTS, it returns 'USER_OBJECTS' WITH Object_Type as 'VIEW' & 'SYNONYMS' and Owner as 'SYS' & 'PUBLIC'

Comment: Sorry I was maybe not clear. Do you have your invalid objects also when you execute  `SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE STATUS='INVALID';`

Comment: Yes it returns., but the object type is 'VIEW' & 'SYNONYMS' but not table.,

Comment: Even after dropping those Pkgs, it stills shows up every time i execute `SELECT * FROM USER_OBJECTS WHERE STATUS='INVALID';`, wat cud be the reason possibly.,?

Comment: How do you drop the packages? Maybe the issue is there. i.e.  `drop package body ` ... will not drop specification.

Comment: I dropped using `DROP PACKAGE PKG1`

Comment: Is it successful? Maybe you have some error when you try to drop it.